# Results for within-subject factors differ between DataDesk and R (package lme4) in linear mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme

This question was initially asked in StackOverflow but someone recommended me to ask it here.

I am new to linear mixed models and lme4. Consequently, I wanted to check the results of my analyses with DataDesk 6.3 and was surprised to obtain different results for the within-subject factor in both softwares. To illustrate what I am saying, here are some dummy data:

```
Sample<-rep(c("sample1","sample2","sample3","sample4","sample5","sample6","sample7",
                      "sample8","sample9","sample10","sample11","sample12","sample13",
                      "sample14","sample15","sample16","sample17","sample18","sample19",
                      "sample20","sample21","sample22","sample23","sample24","sample25",
                      "sample26","sample27","sample28","sample29","sample30"),2)
    
Variable<-c(30.0, 29.6, 30.6, 31.5, 28.7, 30.4, 29.8, 29.8, 29.3, 30.5,
               26.9, 28.2, 27.6, 28.8, 27.4, 26.9, 27.3, 27.9, 29.1, 30.4,
               26.9, 28.9, 26.8, 26.5, 28.8, 26.7, 28.3, 28.7, 28.0, 24.6,
               30.0, 29.4, 28.2, 31.5, 26.5, 25.5, 25.6, 24.6, 30.2, 26.6,
               26.7, 32.7, 28.1, 29.8, 30.5, 27.6, 29.3, 29.2, 28.4, 29.7,
               27.6, 27.3, 30.4, 27.6, 29.1, 32.2, 29.3, 29.4, 29.3, 30.4)
    
Factor1<-rep(c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",10)),2)
    
Repeated<-c(rep("Repeated1",30),rep("Repeated2", 30))
    
Covariate<-rep(c( 12.3, 13.6, 11.6, 11.5, 13.7, 19.2, 16.3, 18.4, 14.9, 15.7, 
                                  10.2, 14.1, 14.8, 10.5, 11.4, 17.1, 11.9, 13.1, 18.6, 19.2, 
                                  17.8, 15.4, 12.9, 15.9, 11.8, 17.9, 16.0, 14.1, 12.3, 10.4),2)
```

“Sample” are the individual subjects. “ Variable ” is my continuous variable of interest. “Factor1” is a between-subject factor. “Repeated” is a within-subject factor. “Covariate” is a between-subject covariate, i.e. “sample1” will have the same “Covariate” value for the “Repeated1” and “Repeated2” factor levels. I want to test the impact of “Factor1”, “Repeated” and “Covariate” on “Variable”.

If I do a type III ANCOVA with DataDesk, I got the following result :

```
Source                     df      Sum of squares      Mean squares      F      P-value
Const                      1         49169.2            49169.2          24110  < 0.001
Factor1                    2         18.45              9.22             4.52   0.02
Covariate                  1         4.46               4.46             2.19   0.15
Factor:Covariate           2         16.92              8.46             4.15   0.03
Subject                    24        48.95              2.04             1.09   0.42
Repeated                   1         1.01               1.01             0.54   0.47
Factor1:Repeated           2         0.88               0.44             0.23   0.79
Covariate:Repeated         1         12.22              12.22            6.54   0.02
Factor1:Covariate:Repeated 2         4.41               2.2              1.18   0.32
Error                      24        44.81              1.87  
Total                      59        180.96
```

With R, I used the lmer function from the package lme4 and did the following:

```
model <- lmer(Variable ~ Covariate*Factor1*Repeated + (1|Sample),
                contrasts = list(Factor1="contr.poly",Repeated="contr.poly"))

Anova(model,type="III",test="F")
```

And I got the following result:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)

Response: Variable
                                  F Df Df.res  Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)                872.9188  1     24 < 2e-16 ***
Covariate                    2.1876  1     24 0.15213    
Factor1                      4.5232  2     24 0.02153 *  
Repeated                     7.0898  1     24 0.01362 *  
Covariate:Factor1            4.1475  2     24 0.02837 *  
Covariate:Repeated           6.5424  1     24 0.01727 *  
Factor1:Repeated             0.2348  2     24 0.79255    
Covariate:Factor1:Repeated   1.1806  2     24 0.32430    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

As you can see, the F and P-values are consistent between DataDesk and R except for the “Repeated” within-subject factor who appears as significant (note that the results of its interactions with “Factor1” and “Covariate” are consistent).

I am able to get a consistent result for “Repeated” if I use type II ANCOVA :

```
Anova(model,type="II",test="F")

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)

Response: Variable
                                 F Df Df.res   Pr(>F)    
Covariate                   1.3583  1     24 0.255283    
Factor1                     0.8757  2     24 0.429476    
Repeated                    0.5431  1     24 0.468294    
Covariate:Factor1           4.1475  2     24 0.028374 *  
Covariate:Repeated          6.3430  1     24 0.018859 *  
Factor1:Repeated           11.6856  2     24 0.000286 ***
Covariate:Factor1:Repeated  1.1806  2     24 0.324299    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

So my questions are:

• What software has the “right” result? Considering that a paired t-test does not indicate significant difference between the 2 levels of “Repeated” (t = 0.52, df = 29, P = 0.61), I would say DataDesk. If yes, why applying a type II ANCOVA is “better” for a within-subject factor?

• If DataDesk is “right”, could I have missed something when coding my linear mixed model with R to not get the appropriate result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you interested in reporting ANCOVA results?

Comment: I am interested in ANCOVA because I have data on stable isotope values measured in liver and muscle of sharks and I wanted to see how these values are influenced by the shark species, their sex (between-subject factors), their size (covariate) and the tissue (within-subject factor).